# How to test the MongoClient (of the reactive streams driver) is actually connected?

Tags: java, mongodb, testing, reactive-streams

When I create a MongoClient using the `MongoClients.create` method, and providing a syntactically right mongo url, yet one that points nowhere, the client is still created.

Then it fails on the following operations.

I tried listing the databases as a way of testing the connection, and it kind of works as a test, yet it takes AGES to fail.

Is there a way to test it's actually connected?

Answer (score 0):

To check whether the driver has a connection to a server you should analyze ClusterDescription. For example, [hasWritableServer](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.6/javadoc/com/mongodb/connection/ClusterDescription.html#hasWritableServer--) says whether there is any connected primary. Also in ClusterDescription you can analyze [ServerDescription](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.6/javadoc/com/mongodb/connection/ServerDescription.html)s that represents each particular server